# Upload photo to Facebook album using user_photos on ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing regarding this, but when using `requestForUploadPhoto` to send a photo to an album, it gets sent up with permission set to 'Only me'. Because the permission setting is so restrictive, photos then need to be manually approved by the user. Is there a way to alter the default upload permission (which will hopefully stop it requiring manual approval)? Normally it would be set when requesting a publish permission, but because user_photos is technically a read permission, I'm not given the chance to specify this. Code is below.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_photos"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    FBRequest* request = [FBRequest requestForUploadPhoto:uploadImage];
    FBRequestConnection* connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection* connection, id result, NSError* error)
        { NSLog(@"Done with upload"); }];
    [connection start];
}];
```

I know it's not even slightly close in terms of catching and managing other session changes, but I'm not fussed with that atm - I just want to get this permission issue resolved before coding the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_photos only allows you to see photos (using GET), and does not allow you to post a photo. To do that, you need either publish_stream or publish_actions. Are you sure your app didn't already have a publish permission somehow?

You are correct in that the privacy is set when an app requests publish permissions, and the user can change that at any point later on as well (via the Facebook app or website).

Comment: I'll mark this one as correct, due to the fact that using `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions: defaultAudience: allowLoginUI: completionHandler:]` with `publish_actions` did work. To answer your question, though, all of the Facebook code in the app is posted in my question. It seems `user_photos` does allow you to upload, just not specifying the permission, unless the convenience method `requestForUploadPhoto` implicitly requests the required permission.